# Returning an array of column data MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know there is mysql_fetch_assoc which puts all data from a row into an array. Is there something equivalent for putting all data in a column into an array? e.g. a list of title ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is probably what you're looking for as it can get everything in one row. You can group all of the values with a comma using `GROUP_CONCAT` and then populate the array using `explode()`.

Your SQL would contain this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',') AS col
```

And your PHP would create the array like this (after performing the query):

```
$col_array = explode(',' $row['col']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $arr[] = $row['id']; // replace id with your column name.
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use external libraries, it may be worth looking into the Zend database library. `Zend_Db` provides a function called [`fetchCol`](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.select.fetchcol) where it will return an array without having to write any additional code.